# I tried updating dictionary with existing dictionaries using update method but its showing error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, dictionary

I HAVE TO UPDATE D1 AND D2 IN D3

```
d1={"adam smith":"A","judy paxton":"B+"}
d2={"mary louis":"A","patrik white":"C"}
d3={}
```

THIS IS MY CODE

```
for item in (d1,d2):
    d3.update({d1:d2})
print(d3)
```

And it giving error unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: `d3={**d1,**d2}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `d3.update(item)` would fix the code.  It's a bit suspicious when a `for` loop body makes no use of the loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in (d1,d2):
    d3.update({d1:d2})
print(d3)
```

It gives you a TypeError, when you are trying to use `d1` as a key, because keys can only be of `hashable` types. You can't use `dict` as a key in another `dict`, unless it is a custom class `dict` where the `__hash__` method is defined.

As it was said, this will do:

```
for item in (d1,d2):
    d3.update(item)
print(d3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
for item in (d1,d2):
    d3.update(item)
print(d3)
```